# Update Asp Net MVC Model after changing Sql Server Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssms

I have created a model from a existing Sql Server db and I was curious if there is a way to update a existing model if I make changes on my sql db structure?

I mean, if I create a table using Sql Server Management Studio, could I update my model in VS?

Thank a lot;

Comment: If you are referring to the database structure, Visual Studio scans the SQL Server database to determine its structure.  Right-click, Refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really would help to know what your "model" is.  If you are using EntityFramework, you will have to update the model from the database (selecting the table you want to add) via the EDMX.